# Run-time error '6': Overflow-Save data into an dynamic array

Tags: vba, excel

I am a newbie of Excel-VBA. My assignment is  to count the number of gateway and the circuit parts of gateway and then show them into a readable report.
My logic is count the number of gateway firstly and then use a do until loop to traverse each row of the data.
Retrieve the circuit parts name and then save to an array which called "parts()" each row.

However the line " j=j+1" throw Run-time error'6':Overflow.

Can anyone help me solve the problems or give me some suggestions?I appreciate any response:)

```
Function countG450(index As Long, gateway As String, gatewayCount As Integer)       
     Dim sheet As Worksheet
     Set sheet = ActiveSheet
     Dim row, rowCount As Range
     Set row = sheet.Rows(1)
     Dim thisRow  As Long        
     Dim parts() As String, partsCount As Integer
     Dim uniqueList() As Variant        
     Dim vertical As String, horizontal As String      
     Dim j As Integer       
     Dim writeIndex As Integer

     index = 1
     writeIndex = 1
     RowIndex = 1

     For i = 0 To gatewayCount
          j = 0
          Do Until Application.CountA(sheet.Rows(RowIndex)) = 0

              'save parts of gateway

              If (Left(Cells(RowIndex, 1), 4) = gateway) And Cells(RowIndex, 2) <> vbstringnull And Cells(RowIndex, 2) <> "ANALOG LINE" And Cells(RowIndex, 2) <> "DIGITAL LINE" Then
                  ReDim Preserve parts(j)
                  parts(j) = Cells(RowIndex, 2)                    
                  **j = j + 1**
              End If

             'Count the circuit parts of analog
             'Count the circuit parts of digtal
              If (Left(Cells(RowIndex, 1), 4) <> gateway And Cells(RowIndex, 1) <> vbstringnull) Then
                  uniqueList = GetUniqueValues(parts)

                  'Write parts of gateway

                  Erase parts
                  Erase uniqueList
                  gateway = Left(Cells(RowIndex, 1), 4)
                  RowIndex = RowIndex + 1

              End If
          Loop
          Dim y As Variant
          y = DrawBorder(horizontal, vertical)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Is j larger than 32,767? You've dimensioned it as an Integer which, in VBA, is a 16-bit signed numeric type that holds between -32,767 and 32,767.

Comment: @SteveS yep except that it can hold values from `-32768 to 32767` due to `0` needing no sign there is enough room for one more negative value but yeah that's the right track